Unable to update ubuntu 24.04 after incorrectly installing debian key
I was attempting to follow the apt instructions for lutris but they're apparently only for debian and I've messed up my apt key for ubuntu so nothing else will update
I used the following commands
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/lutris.gpg] https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_12/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list > /dev/null

echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/lutris.gpg] https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_12/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list > /dev/null

sudo apt update

The error i receive is
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease [256 kB]
Get:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu noble InRelease [48.8 kB]                                                  
0% [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.82)]/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
E: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Err:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu noble InRelease             
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]                       
0% [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.82)]/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
E: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Err:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                  
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease [126 kB]                     
Get:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maveonair/helix-editor/ubuntu noble InRelease [17.8 kB]             
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.82)]/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
E: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Err:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Get:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu noble InRelease [17.8 kB]
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.82)]/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
E: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Err:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
0% [Waiting for headers]/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
E: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maveonair/helix-editor/ubuntu noble InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
0% [Waiting for headers]/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
E: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu noble InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [126 kB]
0% [Working]/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 95: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
E: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
  gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu noble InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu noble InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maveonair/helix-editor/ubuntu noble InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maveonair/helix-editor/ubuntu noble InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu noble InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu noble InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease: gpgv, gpgv2 or gpgv1 required for verification, but neither seems installed
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I tried the following to fix it but it didn't work so i undid it
sudo cp -a /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Is there a way to regenerate the required gpg key for apt please?
EDIT: In response to @organic-marble below:
This is from history
 6413  hx
 6414  top # end of last session
 6415  echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/lutris.gpg] https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_12/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list > /dev/null
 6416  sudo apt update  # this is where the error first occurred
 6417  ll /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
 6418  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list
 6419  sudo hx /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
 6420  sudo apt update
 6421  sudo apt install gpgv
 6422  sudo apt install gpg
 6423  sudo apt update
 6424  cat /etc/apt/sources.list
 6425  cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
...

I checked /dev/null with the following but it's probably not conclusive
sudo cat test.txt > /dev/null

The following requested by @steeldriver
➜  ~ ls -l /dev/null                                                                                           
crw-rw----+ 1 root plugdev 1, 3 Aug 31 15:13 /dev/null

➜  ~ findmnt -T /dev/null
TARGET
     SOURCE
          FSTYPE   OPTIONS
/dev udev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=32815052k,nr_inodes=8203763,mode=755,inode64



Please update your question and show exactly what you did to get into this situation. We don't know what "the apt instructions for lutris" are.

thanks for the recommendation - i'll add that now

That wouldn't have caused this problem if executed properly.

so it may have been a coincidence? hmmm

Can you use the command history to see what commands were actually entered?

I tried the command in a virtual machine. As expected it created  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list. When I do a subsequent apt update I get PUBKEY errors (which are expected, because I didn't add one) but nothing like what you show.

thanks very much for doing that - so this may be an issue with ubuntu itself? I've looked around on google and a few comments come up but nothing conclusive. I'm thinking about seeing if i can repair the install with a live usb or something

I'd not do anything drastic until some more people have a chance to look at this. Some of those repair attempts can make things worse. I don't recognize some of the commands you use like hx so I don't know how to analyze this further.

hx is a modal text editor like vim - nothing untoward there :) but i definitely take your point - i'll wait to nuke the site from orbit

/dev/null is a character special device that should be created at boot time, it should never be necessary for a writing process to create it - the only time I've seen an error like that is in a chroot environment where the chroot dev was not correctly bind mounted (see for example /dev/null permission denied in chroot environment)

One other thing that looks weird to me (which just means I haven't experienced it myself) is the ./ in the deb line that the command adds to the sources list. Instead of that, my deb lines say things like focal restricted etc after the url. But I know the sources list format changed recently, I have no experience with that, and it may be related to that.

i tried removing the the lutris.list from /etc/apt/sources.list.d but it doesn't have any effect

Taken a backup of ~/ with rsync if i can't resolve this :)

... please [edit] your question to include the outputs of ls -l /dev/null and findmnt -T /dev/null

i've addeded that

FWIW, mine is significantly different in both permissions and group crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Aug 31 07:50 /dev/null  

Given that you have done something unfamiliar to you as root, you may have broken other things too. If so, the best approach may be to simply reinstall on top, restore a copy of your current files, and consider this a learning experience. You may want to enable backups before future experimentation to be able to restore broken files.

Based on your ls output:
➜  ~ ls -l /dev/null                                                                                           
crw-rw----+ 1 root plugdev 1, 3 Aug 31 15:13 /dev/null

your /dev/null character device file AFAIK has incorrect group ownership (should be root) and permissions (should be rw-rw-rw-). Additionally, it seems to have some kind of extended file attributes set (indicated by the final +) character.
Correcting the ownership and basic Unix permissions is straightforward with chgrp and chmod but given the unknown extended attributes it may be simpler to re-create the device node (I suggest running lsattr /dev/null first for the record, in case it turns out to have been set intentionally and needs to be restored):
sudo rm /dev/null && sudo mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3

FWIW I can't see anything in your interactive shell history that might have caused this change. If the issue recurs, then I'd suggest checking to see if there's a udev rule somewhere that is modifying the device.

Nice! Today I learned about mknod

me too! That looks like it's resolved the issue. The only bit of strangeness was this at the end of the the sudo apt update: W: Problem unlinking the file lists - pkgAcquire::Clean (21: Is a directory) but it seems to be working. Thanks very much for the help
